# How to parse some text from file in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, file, parsing

Hello i want to parse file with structure like this... after name: {} it can be other things with same form. something: {}.

```
--- 
NAMES: 
  first_thing: {}

  second_thing: {}

  name: {}
```

Thanks for your answers.

I want to parse it to this form

```
first_thing
second_thing
name
```

Comment: It is not possible to answer your question as written. For example, it is unclear what you are trying to parse out of the file, and how it should be structured. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Also, tell us about the things you tried, or state the amount you're willing to pay to get your job done

Comment: i want to delete first 2 lines and with other lines i want only one word without brackets and (:) colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^\s+ (\w+)/x' file
```

On windows:

```
perl -ne "print qq{$1\n} if /^\s+ (\w+)/x" file
```

Comment: Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

Comment: `my $input = "input.txt";
my @myarray = ``perl -ne "print qq{$1\n} if /^\s+ (\w+)/x" $input`;`

Thanks for answer. Can I ask you too how can i transform it to another file? result of myarray to output.txt fo example

Comment: perl -ne "print qq{$1\n} if /^\s+ (\w+)/x" file > output.txt

Comment: ok this I know, but how to call it from other file... not from terminal

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
preg_match_all('/^(\w+):\s(.*?)$/m', $input, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Comment: Undefined subroutine &main::preg_match_all called at test.pl line 5.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/perl
 
my $input = "$input.txt";
my $output = "$output.txt"; 
if (preg_match_all('/^(\w+):\s(.*?)$/m', $input, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
print "SUCCESS";
}
else {
print "FAILED";
}`

Comment: sorry that function is of PHP, I didnot realized you are asking for perl, anyway try this in perl `@output = ($input =~ m/^(\w+):\s(.*?)$/);`